# Can SQLite store/retrieve the .db file from HDFS?

Tags: sqlite, hdfs

I'd like to embed SQLite in my Java application and I'd like it to store/retrieve the .db file from the underlying HDFS. Is it possible?

For example, I was wondering if at DB initialization one can pass the .db file inputStream instead of the file location.

Comment: Do you know the answer?